# Why is major axis of this ellipse is along what appears to be minor axis?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

Given any ellipse in standard form, like

$$x^2/5+y^2/10=1$$ 
is always elongated towards $y$ as its denominator is larger or $b>a$.

But consider this ellipse
$$\frac{\left(x+2y\right)^2}{5}+\frac{\left(2x-y\right)^2}{20}=1$$

This is elongated towards $x+2y=0$, even though it has less denominator.

Whys is that? Can't this ellipse be seen as one with axes $x+2y=0$ and $2x-y=0$

Sketch of this ellipse is here:

[image: here]

Comment: What does it even _mean_ to be elongated towards x+2y=0?

Comment: Major axis is along that line.

Comment: Consider standard ellipse, $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$, This ellipse is elongated along y-axis if $b>a$ and along x-axis if $a>b$. I am talking about elongation along similar lines, but along given lines which substitute x and y.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, graph plotted says its not. I have attached a snapshot

Comment: @Shubham I plotted it myself as well.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, How did you plot the graph?, I used this https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: I used Wolfram Alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x%2B2y)%5E2%2F5+%2B+(2x-y)%5E2%2F20+%3D+1

Comment: That's what I am trying to ask, as $(2x-y)$ term has higher denominator, should it not be major axis.

Comment: **Hint:** There is no inconsistency. Your first ellipse is also "elongated along" the line $x=0$, as the $x$ term has a smaller denominator. Think about the relationship between the $y$-axis and the line $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two cases are similar

- for $x^2/5+y^2/10=1$ when $x=0$ we have the max elongation towards $y$
  (that is $x=0$)
- for $\frac{\left(x+2y\right)^2}{5}+\frac{\left(2x-y\right)^2}{20}=1
  $ when $x+2y=0$ we have the max elongation towards $2x-y$
  (that is $x+2y=0$)

Indeed note that

$$x+2y=0\implies \frac{\left(0\right)^2}{5}+\frac{\left(2x-y\right)^2}{20}=1
\implies \left(2x-y\right)^2=20 \implies25y^2=20\\\implies y=\pm\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}\quad x=\mp\frac{4\sqrt{5}}{5}\implies\rho_1=4\frac{\sqrt{6}}5$$

with $\rho_1$ along the $x+2y=0$ axis.

$$2x-y=0\implies \frac{\left(x+2y\right)^2}{5}+\frac{\left(0\right)^2}{20}=1
\implies \left(x+2y\right)^2=5 \implies25x^2=5\\\implies x=\pm\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}\quad y=\pm \frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5} \implies\rho_2=1$$

with $\rho_2$ along the $2x-y=0$ axis.

Comment: You have shown that it is true, but I was asking why is it true. Anyway thanks, I got it now.

Comment: @Shubham I've just added an explanation, the two cases are similar

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, now seems really silly error which I made. Would upvote, but it requires 15 points.